# How to connect NSTableView with bindings to array(controller) from a different controller?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I've been working on this problem for the last couple of days and coudn't figure it out by myself. I worked through the Apple tutorials and did some research but haven't found an answer yet:

I want to display a view based NSTableView on view "A" but I want to receive the data from the dataController which has the dataArray.

When I put the arrayController on view "A", I can't connect it to my dataArray. When I put it on view "B" from the other controller, I can't connect the NSTableView to it.

Of course I could copy the entire array into the other viewController, work with it and save it back later. But this seems very odd to me.

Thanks for you time!

Comment: Doesn't sounds like you are following the MVC design pattern where the data should be in the 'M' bit and the ViewController should be in the 'V' and/or 'C' bit.

Comment: The data is handled in a dataController which (right now for testing purposes) has a view. But the question stays the same. ;)